# Layouts necessary or not for AndEngine games to be designed for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, andengine

My game developed with AndEngine fits well in tablets. But after submitting on Google Play Store it shows the following Optimization Tip:

```
You uploaded screenshots for 7-inch tablets, but your APK does not seem to be designed for 7-inch tablets.
```

And when I see details in the Optimization Tips, it says:

```
Uses available screen space on 10-inch tablets.
```

My supported SDK versions are,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

After some searching I found that my Manifest.xml file is missing the following:

```
<supports-screens        
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But I also noticed that I am not using any layout files, means, even my layout folder is empty because AndEngine doesn't require any external xml layout files. So, do I also have to produce and provide some empty layout files for different devices, so that Google Play accepts my Game for all devices?

**Edit:**

Now I used 3 blank layout files in 3 different folders for screen supports and uploaded it. Foldernames are layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge. But still I get the same thing:

```
Uses available screen space on 10-inch tablets.
```

Comment: have you tried to create different sized icons for the different device sizes?

Comment: Yes, off-course; and also I recently uploaded new version with different blank layouts for different screens. Foldernames are, layout, layout-large and layout-xlarge. Although now I remember I didn't mention the new layouts in the manifest file. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Im not sure but I think that your app is available to all devices anyways. Optimization tips are just tips you can follow or, in your case, ignore.

Comment: @Orgmir, thanks for your comment. Recently I contacted with google play. They say it's working fine on 7" tablets but crashes on 10" tablets. I wonder why this happens. I neither have a 10" tablet nor the emulator works when I chose a 10" device. I also tried with Genymotion emulator. The emulator crashed after running any app.